# Testing sorting methods

Tags: sorting

I have an assignment requiring use of various sorting methods, specifically bubble sort, insertion sort, quick sort, and heap sort.  We are assigned to write the code to perform each sort on sets of data given to us.  I have written the code for each sort no problem but my question pertains to the second part of our assignment.  We are asked to find the possible conditions we should test to verify that our code works under all cases of input data...I am very lost as to what to do because I can only think of two cases we would deal with:

1) The data is not sorted

2) The data is already sorted

The only conditions I can think of is the size of the data being tested and how "un-sorted" it is.  Am I just thinking about this the wrong way or what?

Note: I am working in C++ although I don't think it matters being that the methodology behind sorting is the same across all languages

Comment: Note: you forgot merge sort (and multiway variants). And radix sort.

Comment: Those sorts aren't in the scope of our assignment.  We only need to worry about the 4 sorts in the question.

Comment: The data can be reversed sorted. That is for some algorithms a worst case scenario.

Comment: A common case is that part of the data is sorted, but a few elements have changed value (or place), or that a few record have been added.

Comment: That makes sense to me but would that not hold true for each sort method?  They obviously sort the data differently but would there be different conditions pertaining to each sort?

Comment: Case where the data is too large to fit in memory.  Case where the data set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257002/what-makes-for-a-bad-case-for-quick-sort) in programmers site.
I guess the best answer is applicable to this question.
I agree to Jongware.
And I have some scripts to generate test data.
    [random.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/random.awk) - random data
    [tim.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/tim.awk) : n-2, n-1, n-4, n-3, ..... , 2, 3, 0, 1 - nearly reversed
    [middle.pl](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/middle.pl) : 5, 3, 1, 2, 4  - middle pivot quicksort killer(PERL script)
    [median3.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/median3.awk) : n-1, 0, 1, 2, ... , n-2 - median-of-3 quicksort killer
    [valley.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/valley.awk) : n-1, n-3, ..., 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, ..., n-4, n-2 - bad case for most quicksort
    [n111.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/n111.awk) : n, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1 - first is big
    [n11n.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/n11n.awk) : n, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1, n - first and last is big
    [n1n1.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/n1n1.awk) : n, 1, n, 1, ..., n, 1 - zigzag
    [nn11.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/nn11.awk) : n, ..., n, 1,..., 1 - few
    [nnnn.awk](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort/blob/master/nnnn.awk) : n, n, ..., n - same
Other n*.awk - awk scripts in [github](https://github.com/leorge/qmisort).

Answer (score 0):

- Empty data
- 1 value of data
- values repeated in the data
- 1 value repeated 20 times
- various permutations of values
- Data sorted in reverse order

What you are looking to find is if your implementation has a defect.  Normally you would create Unit Tests using these conditions...